# Rails controller rspecs fail with RoutingError for spec/controllers but pass for individual tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

My controller specs are passing when I run them one by one but are all failing when I run them together as controllers.

```
$rspec spec/controllers

22) SubjectsController GET index assigns all subjects as @subjects
     Failure/Error: get :index, {}
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"subjects"}
     # ./spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My guess is it must be something to do with database cleaner but I'm not sure best way to troubleshoot routing errors in controller specs.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.13'
gem 'devise', '2.2.3'
...
...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.99'
  gem 'webrick',    '~> 1.3'
  gem 'rails-erd', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'bullet', '~> 4.6'
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.2.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.2'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.6.1'
  gem 'vcr', '~> 2.9.2'
  gem 'webmock', '~>  1.13.0'
  gem 'zeus', '~> 0.13.3'
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rake'
require 'sidekiq/testing'

Sidekiq::Logging.logger = nil


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Only run tests that have this filter, if it exists
  # config.filter_run :debug => true

  # Run all the tests when all the tests are filtered
  # config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new( {
      provider: 'facebook',
      uid: '123545',
      info: {
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
        },
      credentials: {
          token: "123456",
          expires_at: Time.now + 1.week
      },
      extra: {
          raw_info: {
              gender: 'male'
          }
      }
  })

  # silence rspec 3 deprecation warnings
  config.expose_current_running_example_as :example
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  def login(user)
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = user
    @user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  def logged_user
    @user
  end

end
```

spec/support/database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SubjectsController, :type => :controller do

  before(:each) do
    login create(:admin)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all subjects as @subjects" do
      subject = create(:subject)
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:subjects)).to include(subject)
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested subject as @subject" do
      subject = create(:subject)
      get :show, {:id => subject.to_param}
      expect(assigns(:subject)).to eq(subject)
    end
  end

  describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns a new subject as @subject" do
      get :new, {}
      expect(assigns(:subject)).to be_a_new(Subject)
    end
  end

  describe "GET edit" do
    it "assigns the requested subject as @subject" do
      subject = create(:subject)
      get :edit, {:id => subject.to_param}
      expect(assigns(:subject)).to eq(subject)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Subject" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:subject => attributes_for(:subject) }
        }.to change(Subject, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created subject as @subject" do
        post :create, { :subject => attributes_for(:subject) }
        expect(assigns(:subject)).to be_a(Subject)
        expect(assigns(:subject)).to be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to the created subject" do
        post :create, {:subject => attributes_for(:subject) }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(subjects_path)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved subject as @subject" do
        allow_any_instance_of(Subject).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, {:subject => {}}
        expect(assigns(:subject)).to be_a_new(Subject)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        allow_any_instance_of(Subject).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, { :subject => {} }
        expect(response).to render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested subject" do
        @subject = create(:subject, name: "Alice")
        put :update, id: @subject, subject: attributes_for(:subject, name: "Bob")
        @subject.reload
        @subject.name.should eq("Bob")
      end

      it "assigns the requested subject as @subject" do
        @subject = create(:subject)
        put :update, {:id => @subject, :subject => attributes_for(:subject) }
        expect(assigns(:subject)).to eq(@subject)
      end

      it "redirects to the subject" do
        @subject = create(:subject)
        put :update, {:id => @subject, :subject => attributes_for(:subject) }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(edit_subject_path)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns the subject as @subject" do
        @subject = create(:subject)
        allow_any_instance_of(Subject).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => @subject, :subject => {}}
        expect(assigns(:subject)).to eq(@subject)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
        @subject = create(:subject)
        allow_any_instance_of(Subject).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => @subject, :subject => {}}
        expect(response).to render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested subject" do
      subject = create(:subject)
      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => subject.id}
      }.to change(Subject, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the subjects list" do
      subject = create(:subject)
      delete :destroy, {:id => subject.id }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(subjects_url)
    end
  end

end
```

rake routes

```
             suggested_subjects GET    /suggested_subjects(.:format)                             suggested_subjects#index
         make_preferred_subject PUT    /subjects/:id/make_preferred(.:format)                    subjects#make_preferred
                       subjects GET    /subjects(.:format)                                       subjects#index
                                POST   /subjects(.:format)                                       subjects#create
                    new_subject GET    /subjects/new(.:format)                                   subjects#new
                   edit_subject GET    /subjects/:id/edit(.:format)                              subjects#edit
                        subject GET    /subjects/:id(.:format)                                   subjects#show
                                PUT    /subjects/:id(.:format)                                   subjects#update
```

app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.filter(params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {total: @subjects.count, subjects: @subjects}.to_json }
    end
  end
....
....
end
```

Comment: Nothing to do with database. What does Rake Routes say. Also Subject Controller Class would have been way more useful than all that other stuff.

Comment: There you go.  If the spec file passes when running rspec spec/controllers/subjects_controller_spec.rb but fails with routing error when running rspec spec/controllers  must be related to test setup or teardown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The ActionController::RoutingError was a result of another controller spec which was calling:

```
routes.draw
```

This call wiped out the routes for subsequent specs.  The solution for now (thanks to:

http://pivotallabs.com/adding-routes-for-tests-specs-with-rails-3/ ) was to add:

```
after do

    # be sure to reload routes after the tests run, otherwise all your 
    # other controller specs will fail
    Rails.application.reload_routes!

end
```

Also helpful were:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/817

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/636

Hope this helps and good luck!