# Rails4 Rspec Controller Tests No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

All. I am a beginner developer of Ruby on Rails. There is an error that I have been struggling and not been able to solve.

I am trying to see if an variable @chat_group declared in `messages_controller.rb` matches another variable declared in `message_controller_spec.rb`. I have not had any clue to solve this error because I am 100% positive that I am giving what I am supposed to give to as a parameter, which is chat_group_id as the route says.

Does anyone have any insight to solve this problem?
Or has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

If you does or has, could you please give a way of solving this problem?
Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advnace!

```
1) MessagesController#GET index when the user logs in Checking if the variable in index action matches
 Failure/Error: get :index, params: index_params
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages", :params=>{:chat_group_id=>"522"}}
 # ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

messages_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe MessagesController, type: :controller do
  let(:chat_group)    { create(:chat_group) }
  let(:message)       { create(:message) }
  let(:index_params)  { { chat_group_id: chat_group } }

  describe '#GET index' do
    context 'when the user logs in' do
      login_user
      it 'Checking if the variable in index action matches' do
        get :index, params: index_params
        expect(assigns(:chat_group)).to eq chat_group
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Route.rb

```
   chat_group_messages GET    /chat_groups/:chat_group_id/messages(.:format) messages#index
                     POST   /chat_groups/:chat_group_id/messages(.:format) messages#create
         chat_groups GET    /chat_groups(.:format)                         chat_groups#index
                     POST   /chat_groups(.:format)                         chat_groups#create
      new_chat_group GET    /chat_groups/new(.:format)                     chat_groups#new
     edit_chat_group GET    /chat_groups/:id/edit(.:format)                chat_groups#edit
          chat_group PATCH  /chat_groups/:id(.:format)                     chat_groups#update
                     PUT    /chat_groups/:id(.:format)                     chat_groups#update
```

MessageController.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_chat_group

  def index
   @chat_groups = current_user.chat_groups
   @messages = @chat_group.messages
   @message = Message.new

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: 
       @chat_group.messages.includes(:user).map{|x| x.json_api} }
     end
   end

  private
  def set_chat_group
    @chat_group = ChatGroup.find(params[:chat_group_id])
  end
end
```

**Update**

I solved the error! I put the way of solving it in the comments below!

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry. I was looking at a documentation for Rails5 instead of Rails4.

It says that I should pass the `chat_group_id` by writing like below.

Rails4

```
before do
  get :index, { chat_group_id: chat_group }
end
```

Not Like this

```
before do
  get :index, params: { chat_group_id: chat_group }
end
```

This error made me realize how important it is to read the documentation...
For those who put comments and tried to do so, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

try to change `type: controller` to `type: request`?

Also you can use, `request type` and specify path:

```
get chat_group_messages_path(chat_group.id), index_params
```

Cheers

Comment: can you tell me what error you get with this approach ?

Comment: I solved the error! Thank you very much for your help, zauzaj!!

Answer (score 0):

I think You are doing everything right.

but this line : `expect(assigns(:group)).to eq group`

you expected `assigns(:group)` but i can't see any variable named `group` in your index action that you are testing.

also you are expecting that to equal group "`eq group`", but in your `let` blocks in the example above no variable named `group` exists.

So try to do  `expect(assigns(:chat_groups)).to eq chat_group`

the `assigns(:chat_groups)` uses the same name of the instance variable inside your action, and the `eq chat_group` uses the name of the variable in the let block

Comment: you can always refer to the [relish documentation of rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs) for more information, and to see examples.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. It should have said chat_group instead of group, but I copied the wrong term by mistake.

Comment: As you says Abdullah, I read the documentation. However, I haven't gotten a reason why the error 'no routes match' appears even though I am passing chat_group_id, which is required by the route. This bothers me...

Comment: try to request the index action through the browser manually and see if it generates this routing error again or not.

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829707/rails-controller-rspecs-fail-with-routingerror-for-spec-controllers-but-pass-for) on stack overflow, he is having the same error message as you have, check it.

Comment: I solved the error! Thank you very much for your help, Abdullah!!

Comment: Great !, then post your solution and the version of `Rspec` you are using.

Comment: Oh, I already posted the solution to my answer. I would be pleased if you took a look at it! Abdullah